# Load struct from a file in C#

Tags: c#, struct, load

Is it possible to dynamically create structures loaded from files?

For example. File "LOGIN_DATA" with following content:

```
int     id
short     access
string    useraname
string    password
```

From that I want to create a struct name LOGIN_DATA with variables from file content.

Can such thing be done in C#?

Comment: Do you mean create the struct type itself based on the file contents, or read the file contents into a struct type that already exists?

Comment: In other words - do you want a .cs file that you can then add to your project; or do you want a type, created while running your program, and then used via reflection?

Comment: Could you provide the physical layout of the content in the file, meaining? are they fixed lenght? or delimited by some special char, etc, based on that you would want to read each field and probably createdynamic types using  [Reflection.Emit](http://geekswithblogs.net/johnsPerfBlog/articles/49829.aspx)

Comment: Create struct type itself based on file contents.

Comment: Still ambiguous. LOL But, it seems you already have the stuct defined, and you just want to instantiate it with the data from the file. Is that correct?

Comment: @user621033: why do you need specifically a struct to represent something you apparently want to consider as structurally dynamic (otherwise why would not you use a "hardcoded" struct in conjunction with serialization, or if you truly want to have a dynamically defined structure, a dictionary of strongly typed values or an ExpandoObject for example)?

Comment: But how are you going to use that structure after you created it? You wan't be able to do anything useful with it in your current code until compiler knows about it. Are you going to generate programs which will  utilise that structure?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the [TypeBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.aspx) Class could be of use in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

**[15 Seconds : Serialization in the .NET Framework](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020903.htm)**

Comment: @user621033, if type exists then serialization will be the way to load your type from the serialized form (file, database, network stream). I will suggest that you refine your question to state your requirement/problem and that may help to get the answer that you are seeking.